# Is it best practice to create signature fields with relation values?

Tags: alloy

A store has customers. Each customer logs into the store using their userID and password.

I want to create an Alloy function (`fun`) that, when passed credentials (userID and password), returns the customer possessing those credentials:

```
fun customerWithTheseCredentials[userID: UserID, password: Password]: Customer {
    ???
}
```

I have convinced myself that, to accomplish this, I must declare the customer signature this way:

```
sig Customer {
    credentials: UserID lone -> lone Password
}
```

By creating the signature that way, I can implement the function this way:

```
fun customerWithTheseCredentials[userID: UserID, password: Password]: Customer {
    credentials.password.userID
}
```

Had I created the customer signature this way:

```
sig Customer {
    userID: UserID,
    password: Password
}
```

then I could not have implemented the function. Do you agree?

I am coming to the conviction that it is always better to design signature fields with values that are relations (e.g., `credentials: UserID lone -> lone Password`) rather than sets (e.g., `userID: UserID`). Have you also come to that conviction?

Below is my Alloy model:

```
sig UserID {}
sig Password {}
sig Customer {
    credentials: UserID lone -> lone Password
} 

fun customerWithTheseCredentials[userID: UserID, password: Password]: Customer {
    credentials.password.userID
}

run {}

fact Every_customer_has_a_different_password_userID {
    // Every customer has a different userID
    no disj c, c': Customer | 
        c.credentials.Password = c'.credentials.Password
    // Every customer has one userID/password pair
    all c: Customer |
        one id: UserID |
            one p: Password |
                c.credentials = id -> p
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I disagree, You could use set comprehension to easily retrieve the set of customers having the id and password given as parameter.

Have a look at this model (I took the liberty to not assume that each customer has different password ("password123" is only too common ;-)).

```
sig UserID {}
sig Password {}
sig Customer {
    id :disj UserID,
    password: Password
} 

fun customerWithTheseCredentials[userID: UserID, pass: Password]: Customer {
    {c:Customer| c.id=userID and c.password=pass}
}

run {}
```

Comment: Ahhh! I had not thought of using set comprehensions. Thank you @Loïc Gammaitoni

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is an area I work in so I could not show an example where the password would not be treated with more care :-) I know it is just an example but people died because of an insecure password model! (I like the hyperbole.) As a modularity freak I also think you should separate the task of authentication from the retrieval of the Customer, they are not inherently coupled so should be separate.

My model would therefore be:

```
sig UserId, PasswordDigest {}
sig Password { digest : disj PasswordDigest }

sig Customer {
    identity : disj UserId
}

one sig Authenticator {
    db : UserId lone -> one PasswordDigest
}

pred authenticate[ id : UserId, password : Password ] {
    password.digest in Authenticator.db[id]
}

fun customerWithTheseCredentials[ userid: UserId, password : Password ] : lone Customer {
    authenticate[ userid, password ] => identity.userid else none
}

run { #Customer = 3 and #Password=3}
```